# How can an iOS app written in Swift be notified when USB flash drives connect or disconnect?

Tags: swift, usb

I'm working on an iOS app written in Swift and I want to be able to detect when USB flash drives are connected or disconnected from the device. How can I do this in my app?
I've looked into using the External Accessory framework, but I'm not sure how to get started. Can anyone provide some guidance or point me to some resources that can help me implement this feature in my app?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```swift
let keys: [URLResourceKey] = [
    .volumeNameKey, .volumeIsRemovableKey, 
    .volumeIsEjectableKey, .volumeAvailableCapacityKey,
    .volumeTotalCapacityKey, .volumeUUIDStringKey, 
    .volumeIsBrowsableKey, .volumeIsLocalKey, .isVolumeKey
]
let manager = 
    FileManager.default.mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys: keys)

if let urls = manager {
    print(urls)
}
```

This code for example works on MacOS , I get a list of volumes.
However, in iOS it just returns nil.

Comment: I've never used that framework, but looking at [Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory) it looks like you call `EAAccessoryManager`'s `registerForLocalNotifications()` method, then you''ll receive `EAAccessoryDidConnect` notifications via `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: It would help if you showed what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: More context was added.

Comment: That code uses `FileManager` not `EAAccessoryManager`, and if it worked on macOS, I'm thinking the app where you tried it wasn't sandboxed, because external volumes wouldn't be in the sandbox.  It also doesn't notify you when volumes are connected and disconnected, though I suppose you could periodically poll for it.  If you're OK with that approach I notice that `EAAccessoryManager` has a `connectedAccessories` property.  You could poll on that.

Comment: Correct. The idea is to get connection and disconnection events from usb sticks. For FileManager I would periodically poll it. For EAAcessoryManager, I registered for notifications as you said and declared my AppDelegate class (SwiftUI) as the EAAccessoryDelegate. Still no notifications being delivered. I suspect that "External accessory" needs to be MFI Verified

Comment: Though I haven't tried it, I wouldn't expect `FileManager` polling to work because of sandboxing.  `EAAccessoryManager` is the approach I'd expect to work, though I'd also expect that it would add more steps, since you'd need to filter out only flash drive devices, and somehow get the volume's URL from the `EAAccessory`.  Still that's where I'd start.